# How to fix histogram about apperance and remove empyties?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have datas for example, A.
A' s mean is 50.966771, min and max values 0.0, 19955.1 respectively.

I need to do histogram i did but it is not showing good how can i fix, why they are like square, they are not with ups and downs, is it normal as histogram and why they have empty places, how to fix it?

my code for A:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (35,15))
plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.subplot(421)
plt.hist(df_3['adrenal gland'], color = 'blue', bins = 5, density = True)
plt.title("A",size =30)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m0vV.png)

Comment: Try increasing the number of `bins` or try `df = df[df['ColName'] != 0]` to drop any rows with `0` for data.

Comment: how to arrange expecially x line, because so much empty there is after almost 4000

Comment: what is the results of `df_3['adrenal gland'].quantile([0,.25, .5,.75,1])` ?

Comment: 0.00        0.00
0.25        0.10
0.50        3.80
0.75       24.05
1.00    19955.10
Name: adrenal gland, dtype: float64

Answer (score 0):

As I asked you in the comments to get

```
df_3['adrenal gland'].quantile([0,.25, .5,.75,1])
```

you replied that the results are

```
0.00 0.00
0.25 0.10
0.50 3.80
0.75 24.05
1.00 19955.10
```

25% of your data below the value of 0.10

50% of your data below the value of 3.8 (median)

75% of your data below the value of 24.05

and as you mentioned in the question, then the mean is 50

you have extreme values that affect the histogram shape, so remove the extreme values and you will get the expected histogram.

try

```
extreme_values=1000 # for example
plt.hist(df_3[df_3['adrenal gland']<extreme_values]['adrenal gland'], color = 'blue', bins = 100, density = True)
```

you find it is a skewed histogram

Comment: How to determine extreme values, is it standard value or it is up to me?

Comment: try `df_3['adrenal gland'].quantile([0.99])` or 0.95